# get_browser() not working in wamp server

Tags: php

I am working on PHP 5.5.12 and I was trying to use get_browser(); function. But it is not working at all. I am getting the following error:

> Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in C:\wamp\www\Detecting a Visitors Browser.php on line 5

I have download one named `php_browscap.ini`, it didn't work.

I am using wamp as my localhost. I set the location of browscap file in php.ini file:

```
[browscap]
;http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php_browscap.ini"
```

Still it gives me that error I mentioned above.

My code is:

```
$browser = get_browser(null,true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Comment: Have you put the php_browscap.ini file in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php_browscap.ini and reload all services ?

Comment: yes I have done all these things but still not working